# How to customize the django-ratelimit 403 forbidden page?

Tags: python, django, web-frameworks, vs-web-site-project

I'm using django-ratelimit 2.0 for rate limiting my views. I want to show a different (custom) 403 forbidden page for different views. For example if it is a sign up view, it should give a message try again in 1 minute. If it is a forgot password view then message should be try again after 12 hours. Basically I want different rate limit message for different views.

Comment: It's in the [docs](https://django-ratelimit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#ratelimit.exceptions.Ratelimited)

Comment: But it has only one view/rate limit message for different views.

Comment: You could use the Middleware mentioned because there you have access to the `request` object. If that's not good enough, because you can't figure the message from the `request` and actually would like the rate limits that were set, I would change the code: In the decorator, pass the parameters you need to the exception, rewrite the exception to store these parameters as attributes and then you can see them in your handler403.

Comment: Can you give the example. For example I want the exception message for login view to be " try after few minutes" and exception message for forgot password view to be " try after one day"

Answer (score 0):

this will help you
https://django-ratelimit.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#ratelimit.exceptions.Ratelimited

settings.py

```
DEBUG = False

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from ratelimit.decorators import ratelimit  # 进行请求限制
from ratelimit.exceptions import Ratelimited  # 进行请求限制,判断403
# Create your views here.


@ratelimit(key='ip', rate='2/m',block=True)
def Hello(request):
    return render(request, 'hello.html')


def handler403(request, exception=None):
    if isinstance(exception, Ratelimited):
        return HttpResponse('Sorry you are blocked', status=429)
    return HttpResponse('Forbidden')
```

urls.py

```
handler403 = views.handler403
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit what the core idea of your solution is, also to help future users beyond the original question poster.